# How Do I Stop HP X3500 Mouse Changing DPI Settings When I Hold Down Left + Right Buttons?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, drivers, mouse

I have purchased the HP X3500 wireless mouse, and frequently interact with applications which require me to simultaneously click on the left and right mouse buttons. Every time I do this the DPI value is changed (since holding them both down for 3 seconds each and moving the mouse changes the DPI). This is due to a feature with the mouse.

How can I disable this? The mouse itself did not come with any bundled software.

Comment: It is probably not possible to disable this feature of the mouse. Out of curiosity, which application requires you to press both buttons for more than 3 seconds? Could it be that this gesture is actually an emulation of a middle button and that you could use the wheel (which probably also works as a middle button when pressed) to the same effect?

Comment: @nitro2k01 - It is a graphical application which has different behaviour when holding down both buttons and moving the mouse to drag something. When doing so, the DPI is changed everytime.

Comment: Which application?

Comment: It is a bespoke one for our workplace. Does not allow the mouse behaviour to be customised, so I require this to be disabled from the mouse.

Comment: What happens in this application if you use the middle button (the wheel) instead of left+right?

Comment: Nothing happens - it does not have the same effect.

Comment: If this is an internal application application, I would suggest that you request that to be added as a feature if possible. Otherwise, I think it's very likely that this feature is hardcoded in the mouse and cannot be disabled. Ie, the DPI setting is happening all inside the mouse and doesn't involve the OS. Good luck, though.

Comment: That's what I am suspecting, however I was hoping that I could download some software which "overrides" the mouse commands.

Comment: Verify there is no software for the mouse, if there is, install it and change the configuration of the mouse key macro.

Comment: There is no compatible software for this specific mouse. Are there any 3rd party software, or am I stuck like this?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a workaround, but following my suggestion in the comments to use the middle button instead of left+right, you could use an application called [X-Mouse](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to achieve this.

1. Download and install the application.
2. Start X-Mouse and click Add under Application/Window Profiles.
3. Find and select your application and click ok. (Optional - if you want to keep the middle button working normally in other application, as opposed to changing the setting for the default profile. You should even be able to customize exactly for which windows in the application the rule is applied if necessary.)
4. In the right panel, for Middle Button, select Simulated Keys in the dropdown menu.
5. As custom keys, enter `{LMB}{RMB}`
6. How to send the simulated keytrokes: "3 During".
7. Finally click ok and then apply in the main window.

Your middle button should now work as left+right, in this specific application only. This is just a workaround, but I hope it might be enough to use this mouse without getting annoyed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - however I have just tried the middle button and it appears to have its own functionality. I apologise as I assumed that it didn't, but it does seem to do something different.